# How to display list process, when i run sql*loader in c#

Tags: c#

How to display list process, when i run sql*loader in c#. I mean when i run sql*loader from cmd windows, i get list process how many row has been inserted. But when i run SQL*Loader from C#, i can't get process SQL*Loader.

This is my code:

```
string strCmd, strSQLLoader;
string strLoaderFile = "XLLOAD.CTL";
string strLogFile = "XLLOAD_LOG.LOG";
string strCSVPath = @"E:\APT\WorkingFolder\WorkingFolder\sqlloader\sqlloader\bin\Debug\8testskrip_HTTP.csv";
string options = "OPTIONS (SKIP=1, DIRECT=TRUE, ROWS=1000000,BINDSIZE=512000)";
string append = "APPEND INTO TABLE XL_XDR FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
string table = "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' TRAILING NULLCOLS (xdr_id,xdr_type,session_start_time,session_end_time,session_last_update_time,session_flag,version,connection_row_count,error_code,method,host_len,host,url_len,url,connection_start_time,connection_last_update_time,connection_flag,connection_id,total_event_count,tunnel_pair_id,responsiveness_type,client_port,payload_type,virtual_type,vid_client,vid_server,client_addr,server_addr,client_tunnel_addr,server_tunnel_addr,error_code_2,ipid,c2s_pkts,c2s_octets,s2c_pkts,s2c_octets,num_succ_trans,connect_time,total_resp,timeouts,retries,rai,tcp_syns,tcp_syn_acks,tcp_syn_resets,tcp_syn_fins,event_type,flags,time_stamp,event_id,event_code)";

strCmd = "sqlldr xl/secreat@o11g control=" + strLoaderFile + " LOG=" + strLogFile;
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di;

try
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo cmdProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    di = new DirectoryInfo(strCSVPath);

    strSQLLoader = "";
    strSQLLoader += "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + strCSVPath.ToString().Trim() + "' " + append + " " + table;

    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strLoaderFile);
    writer.WriteLine(strSQLLoader);
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

    // Redirect both streams so we can write/read them.
    cmdProcessInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmdProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmdProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmdProcessInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);

    // Start the procses.
    System.Diagnostics.Process pro = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmdProcessInfo);


    // Issue the dir command.
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmd);

    // Exit the application.
    pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");


    //Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    //foreach(Process pro in processlist){
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", pro.ProcessName, pro.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(pro.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    //}

    // Read all the output generated from it.
    string strOutput;
    strOutput = pro.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    pro.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return;
}
finally
{

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you send

```
pro.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

to the process, this will close the console and exit the process.

So when you call

```
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", pro.ProcessName, pro.Id);
```

it raises a

> "Process has exited, so the requested
>   information is not available."

exception. To fix this, move your exit call to after this line.

**Never ignore exceptions!!!** They tell you useful things that help you to fix your problems!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still not display process SQL*Loader..I want show process like this, example: save data point reached - logical record count 1000000.. etc